# Why do I see multiple running instances of the same service (Elasticsearch) on Ubuntu, but only one is responsive?

Tags: java, ubuntu, elasticsearch, salt-stack

I am running Elasticsearch (ES) on a small AWS Ubuntu box, and working on tuning the performance of the box overall.

After a recent deploy using Saltstack, I noticed the number of running instances went from two to three -- after being at two for several months. The uptick in instances seems to correspond to an uptick in memory usage.
[image]

I confirmed with ps that there are three java processes running on the box:

```
PID TTY          TIME CMD
9295 ?         00:02:08 java
14398 ?        00:00:12 java
26175 ?        00:40:48 java
```

When I stop ES with command "sudo service elasticsearch stop", I was still left with two ES processes running according to ps:

```
PID TTY          TIME CMD
9295 ?         00:02:08 java
26175 ?        00:40:48 java
```

I restarted the service and then I had three again. This seems really strange two me because it seemed like two of the services were unresponsive to the stop command. (Could this be a so-called Zombie or Orphan process?)

I manually killed all three processes and restarted ES, and now have only a single ES instance. I wondered if these wayward java processes were related to some other service, but after killing all three, New Relic confirmed a large drop in memory usage and processes -- so they were definitely all ES-related processes:

[image]

My question is why, after a deploy, would the number of running instances go up? 
Is there a functional Elasticsearch reason for this, or was this a bug?
What would cause either Elasticsearch or any service on Ubuntu in general to go into this unresponsive state?

Any insight is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you install anything that might have an embedded Elasticsearch? Kibana, Logstash, others?

Answer (score 0):

What do you get when running this command:

```
 lsof -i :9200-9399 | tail -n +2 | awk '{print $2}' | xargs ps -p
```

`lsof -i :9200-9399` will list all open files on the port range 9200-9399, i.e. the default port range used by ES. Change the range if your configuration differs.

`tail -n +2` will ditch the first output line from the `lsof` command, it contains column headers and it's not useful

`awk '{print $2}'` will fetch only the process id (PID) from the `lsof` output

Finally, `xargs ps -p` will run the `ps` command to find out what process runs under the PID fetched by the `awk` command.

You should get an output like below and that might get you started in your investigation.

```
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
21199 ttys011    4:39.26 /usr/bin/java -Xms256m -Xmx1g....
22234 ttys012    5:12.22 /usr/bin/java -Xms256m -Xmx1g....
23444 ttys013    3:33.54 /usr/bin/java -Xms256m -Xmx1g....
```

Comment: Hi @Val, I added the output of my PS commands to the question above. How would you go about investigating from here? I'm not familiar with this stuff, so I'm not exactly sure what I'm looking at!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Any chance to get the full command line instead of just `java` in the CMD column? Perhaps using `ps -p 9295`? Also did you install anything that might have an embedded Elasticsearch? Kibana, Logstash, others?

Comment: I will add a more complete output if I can get it to happen again!

Comment: Any news on this ?

Comment: I haven't seen it happen again. So odd!